# can anyone guide me how to install solana/web3.js in react native application. I am getting BigInt related errors?

Tags: web3.js, wallet, mobile

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BigInt
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in errorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in 
at node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.43.82:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Add big-integer to your list of dependencies:

```
yarn add big-integer
```

#### 2. Add a reference in shim.js

there’s a polyfill for Android

```
if (typeof BigInt === 'undefined') global.BigInt = require('big-integer')
```